# Spelling username in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I noticed something strange.

Say your name is Uma Thurman and you make a Gmail account as follows:

umathurman@gmail.com with password Hunter2

And you make another account:

uma.thurman@gmail.com with password deerMe

Then you login to Gmail with username uma.thurman@gmail.com with password Hunter2 it logs in to umathurman@gmail.com, how is that possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the answers to [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14668/why-does-google-not-consider-dot-in-usernames-of-gmail-addresses).

Comment: "And you make another account" - Well, Google won't allow you to create another account that differs only in _dot_ placement. As it states on the account signup page, "Note that we ignore full stops and capitalisation in usernames.". - Are you suggesting that the second account creation appeared to be successful?

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the comments, creating an account that differs only in the existence or placement of a dot is not allowed by Google, as Google ignore dots and capitalization in email addresses. This makes the two names reach the same account *unless* the account containing a dot was created very early in Gmail's beginnings (i.e. not created after the one without the dot), or if both of the accounts are Google Apps accounts.

Source: [Why does Google not consider dot in usernames of Gmail addresses?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14668/why-does-google-not-consider-dot-in-usernames-of-gmail-addresses)