# Gmail account received another person's email

Tags: gmail

My Gmail address is my full name with a dot between my first and last name. I periodically receive emails for another person with the same name add me however his address DOES NOT have a period between his first and last name.

I usually inform the sender that the email was delivered to the wrong person (ray.mckenzie@)and to make sure they do not put a dot between the first and last name (raymckenzie@). The sender replies that they have in fact NOT put a dot between first and last name and still the email gets delivered to me.

Can you look into this and let me know what's going on?

Comment: Related http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14668/87130

Answer (score 2):

Both emails are, in fact, the same for Google.  Google processes all emails with periods by removing all of them and then sending the email out.

If you sent an email to the following emails, they would all be directed to the same person.

- ray.mckenzie@gmail.com
- r.a.y.m.c.k.e.n.z.i.e@gmail.com
- raymckenzie@gmail.com

**Note:** This is *only* true for Google, so my guess is that whoever is sending you email simply sent their message to the wrong email address, and that this other Ray has a similar Gmail email, but not the same.  Maybe `RayPMcKenzie` or something of that matter.

Comment: So this issue isn't the fact that OP is receiving someone else's email due to a Google error, but rather the sender is sending to the wrong email.  Sort of like a wrong number in a phone call.

Answer (score 1):

Both email address 'ray.mckenzie@gmail.com' and 'raymckenzie@gmail.com' belongs to you only.

Form [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?query=username&topic=0&type=f#):

> **Gmail doesn't recognize dots as characters within usernames**, you can add or remove the dots from a Gmail address without changing the actual destination address; they'll all go to your inbox, and only yours. In short:
>
> homerjsimpson@gmail.com = hom.er.j.sim.ps.on@gmail.com
>   homerjsimpson@gmail.com = HOMERJSIMPSON@gmail.com
>   homerjsimpson@gmail.com = Homer.J.Simpson@gmail.com
>
> All these addresses belong to the same person. You can see this if you try to sign in with your username, but adding or removing a dot from it. You'll still go to your account.