# Receiving Gmail to an account that is not linked to my email address

Tags: gmail

I keep getting email sent to similar email addresses as mine.  for example, if my email address is:  `jfrank@gmail.com`, I also get emails addressed to `j.frank@gmail.com`.  This j.frank email is not associated with my email address, so I cannot remove the association.

How can I block these type emails?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail ignores dots in email addresses, `j.frank@gmail.com` is the same as `jfrank@gmail.com` is the same as `j.f.r.a.n.k@gmail.com`.

It would seem that someone registered for something and put in the wrong address. Unless you can get the sender to stop sending it, your only option is to create a filter on that variant that'll automatically delete those messages. (This assumes, of course, that you'd never want to use that address variant yourself.)

Comment: See also: [Why does Google not consider dot in usernames of Gmail addresses?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14668/354)

Comment: I didn't realize that the dots were ignored.  I'd send them an email (but it would just come back to me).  This is so annoying, it happens a lot.  Thanks for your reply.