# I am receiving email that is not mine

Tags: gmail

My email address is guerrero.daisy@gmail.com. I have been receiving emails from guerrerodaisy@gmail.com. I am concerned that this user is receiving my emails as I have been receiving her emails. How do I correct this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail ignores dot `.` signs in email addresses, so those emails are being addressed to you. Similarly, g.uerrerodaisy@gmail.com and gue.rrer.odaisy@gmail.com would also go to your inbox.

For more info, see this Google support email [Dots don't matter in Gmail addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150)

Comment: There are [multiple reports](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90466) of distinct accounts that differ by dots only.